# MYSQL requires group by but query produces wrong results with it

Tags: mysql

Given a table that looks like this

```
reportID username
-----------------
1      | a
1      | b
1      | c
2      | a
3      | c
3      | a
```

Given a query that takes in 2 or more usernames it should return the rows which contain both usernames and a matching reportID.

For example if given a and b it would return

```
reportID username
-----------------
1      | a
1      | b
```

Since they share a reportID.

```
SELECT reportID, username 
FROM players 
WHERE username IN('a', 'b') 
group by reportID, username
having count(reportID) > 1
```

Is as close as I can get. Adding the group by username ruins the query and returns 0 results but it's required as without it this error is produced:

```
1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains 
nonaggregated column 'x.x.username' which is not functionally dependent on 
columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: The result is written in the question underneath "For example if given a and b it would return"

Comment: Just look the answer.. he gave an example of expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT reportID, username 
FROM players 
WHERE reportID in (
  select reportID
     from players where username IN('a', 'b') 
     group by reportID
     having count(reportID) > 1
)
```

Comment: You're definitely the closest and I could make due with this if I have to through PHP but it also returns results for other usernames like 1 c (which I've added to the OP)

Comment: A simple amendment - just add a where condition at the end

Comment: Yeah that would do it alright, I can't even think any more after staring at this for so long. I proposed an edit to fix it up because that works.

Answer (score 0):

Having count is useless just do this :

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE username IN ('a', 'b') group by username
```

Comment: I only want the ones that they share, this returns all of them for each.

Comment: Don't see how that would be possible. You'd end up with 1a, 1b, 2a, 3a.

Comment: I just created your table example and test query...
This query return your expected result...

Comment: Instead of imagine that is impossible go try and come back

Comment: I have. First off it doesn't even run because of the error I posted above. Without grouping by the username this fails and upon adding one it returns 0 values.

Comment: This query returns the correct result purely by chance - the group by is invalid for this purpose and won't even syntax if only_full_group_by is set (as it is by default in more recent versions of mysql)